# How to set backgroung color to the selected node of DevComponents.AdvTree.AdvTree?

Tags: c#, dotnetbar

I am using `DevComponents.AdvTree.AdvTree` in my c# project to which i new.Now i want to change the Background color of selected node of that tree on a button click. I have searched a lot but did not found any property that can set `BackColor` as in normal TreeView Control.
  So , please can anyone help me to set it . Thank you in advance for help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found solution myself:

```
                DevComponents.AdvTree.Node node = new DevComponents.AdvTree.Node();
                node = advTree1.SelectedNode;
                node.Style = new DevComponents.DotNetBar.ElementStyle(); 
                node.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```